# SamAccountName from csv with employeeid

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, system-administration

I have this working script:

```
    Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Script\fi13.04.20.csv" | ForEach-Object {

    Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeid -like '*$($_.employeeid)*'"  -Properties employeeid | select employeeid,name,SamAccountName

} | Export-CSV "$home\desktop\Script\fi-san-out.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

I give to him a CSV file with employeeid and have back file with SamAccountName...
Я даю ему файл с employeeid и получаю обратно файл with certain parameters.

And this is an improved version-

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Script\fi13.04.20.csv"

$csvOutput = "$home\desktop\Script\fi-san-out.csv"

$object = @()

foreach($employee in $csv){

    $ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($employee.employeeID)'" -Properties samAccountName, displayName ,employeeID  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($ADUserObject){

        $object += New-Object psobject -Property @{

            displayName = $ADUserObject.displayName

            samAccountName = $ADUserObject.SamAccountName

            employeeID = $ADUserObject.employeeID

        }

    }else{

        Write-Host "No employee found for $($employee.employeeId)" -ForegroundColor Red

    }

}

if($object){

    $object | Select-Object displayName, samAccountName, employeeID | Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation

}
```

The first version produces much more results because if the employeeID contains an error "for example, the employeeID in CSV 12345 and employeeID in ActiveDirectory 123456", it gives the result.
In the improved version, it throws an error with any inaccurate ID.
The question is how to change the improved version so that it produces a result even with an error(like in the example)?
I am just starting to learn PS and I wrote an improved version with the help.

Comment: is there some reason you cannot simply swap the `"employeeID -eq '$($employee.employeeID)'" ` test in the 2nd code sample with the `"employeeid -like '*$($_.employeeid)*'"` test in the 1st code sample?

Comment: I try this. but the problem not solved.

Comment: at what point in the 2nd code sample does the code NOT give what you expect ... and how does the actual result differ from the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Result

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Script\ID.csv"

$csvOutput = "$home\desktop\Script\tz-san-out.csv"

$object = @()

foreach($employee in $csv){

    $ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -like '*$($employee.employeeID)*'" -Properties samAccountName, displayName ,employeeID  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($ADUserObject){

        $object += New-Object psobject -Property @{

            displayName = $ADUserObject.displayName

            samAccountName = $ADUserObject.SamAccountName

            employeeID = $ADUserObject.employeeID

        }

    }else{

        Write-Host "No employee found for $($employee.employeeId)" -ForegroundColor Red

    }

}

if($object){

    $object | Select-Object displayName, samAccountName, employeeID | Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation

}
```